# How to use snippet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xcode

```
$(function() {

   var docHeight = $(document).height();

   $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");

   $("#overlay")
      .height(docHeight)
      .css({
         'opacity' : 0.4,
         'position': 'absolute',
         'top': 0,
         'left': 0,
         'background-color': 'black',
         'width': '100%',
         'z-index': 5000
      });

});
```

i got this from `css-tricks` but i do not know how to use it. Linking to jsfiddle examples would greatly help!

Comment: It would help if you give us a bit of context. What do you want to do? You don't want how to include the script in your page, which variables are defined, how it adapts to your situation?

Comment: I actually just want to know how this snippet works as i'm a beginner and I only know java and php. ANy content would do fine. THank you!

Comment: First sentence retrieves the document height, second adds an overlay node to the document body, and third adds CSS properties to the node just created. You have to put it inside the classical <script> tags to get it to work in your HTML page. However it's a function you have to assign to a variable and call it to make it actually work.

Comment: @jjmerelo your last sentence is misleading.  @Mark Notice that the function is wrapped in `$(`...`);`, which (assuming you're using jQuery) is shorthand for `jQuery(document).ready(`...`);`, which means it'll be called automatically when the page is ready.  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, feel free to edit.

Comment: You can't edit other people's comments :)  PS, you've now got 50 rep so you can now add comments to other people's questions/answers - the sort of answer you gave here really belongs as a comment.

Comment: You need to include **in your question** what this snippet is supposed to do and what your problem is rather than make people guess or have to spend time parsing the comments to find out. When you've done that please flag to re-open.

Answer (score 1):

Here some snippet, which launches overlay when anchor is clicked, can you be more specific, what do you need?

http://jsfiddle.net/ptczS/1/